# git/ Github notification on pull request involving subfolder

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to setup a trigger with git or github s.t. I'm notified if a subfolder of a git repo is updated?

Or better, is it possible to setup a trigger s.t. I'm notified if a pull request involves a subfolder of a git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [GitHub webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to:

1. send a payload to an integration service (ifttt, zapier, elasti.io, etc.)
2. filter/search the payload for the condition you are seeking
3. notify via your preferred method :)

Without GitHub, you could accomplish this using your scripting language of choice via [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

Unfortunately, GitHub does not support git hooks, but other git hosting services do.